I hope you did as well
a. I learned a lot writing this essay, and I hope you did too.
b. I learned a lot writing this essay, and I hope you did as well.
c. I learned a lot writing this essay, and I hope you did also.
To me these sentences mean you wrote this essay
with me and I hope you learned a lot while writing it.
Could they also mean
I learned a lot writing this essay, and I hope you learned a lot reading it.
?
Are the sentences ambiguous?
Many thanks

I hope you did too does not have an explicit object, so yes it's ambiguous. The only thing we can assume is that "you learned a lot". Your learning could be as the co-writer, or as the reader, or indeed as the editor or the long-suffering partner. It's simply unstated in that one sentence.

It's silly to suggest the words are "ambiguous" - by the very nature of the possible contrived alternative sense (that both speaker and addressee wrote the same essay), they would both know perfectly well if that sense applied, so no ambiguity could arise. Also, see this usage chart showing that although all three forms occur, too is far more common than as well or also.

If I meant the second one, I would say something like "I hope you learned from it too" - otherwise, to me, it does imply that the addressee co-wrote it.


I learned a lot writing this essay, and I hope you did too.

I add to @FumbleFingers’ comments.
If the listener co-wrote the essay, he’d know the learning the speaker enquires about refers to the co-writing experience.  The co-writer is unlikely to isolate the writing part and gauge the amount learned just from his or her reading activity.  This is even if he or she has read many more times after some fine tuning from editors.
If the speaker is addressing a crowd, each listener will be understood to interpret the message from his or her standpoint.
There’s no ambiguity.
I borrow FF’s chart showing that the too version is much more common than the other two versions.  All three mean the same.
